# Disable ASP.NET OutputCache for some conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to disable `OutputCache` attribute for some conditions? For example, for admin users?

And another question, I try to implement my `ActionFilterAttribute` inheriting from `OutputCacheAttribute`. I override `OnActionExecuting`, `OnResultExecuted`, `OnResultExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` methods. I set breakpoints in this methods and run project on **IIS Express**. In first time breakpoints is work, but in the cache hit case the breakpoints not working and I have no idea why! It seems like cache working on more high level, for example on **IIS Express** level, and the request pipeline does not reach `ActionsFilters`. By the way, cacheLocation is ClientServer.

Comment: To disable cache in some cases just implement your own caching attribute, in it put your condition and if it's true, then return from the method (if the user is admin) otherwise return base.OnAction.... to enable cache

Comment: OK, but I have a trouble with this solution. I describe his is second paragraph of my question.